# Number of polyhedron diagonals

Tags: geometry

Suppose that I have a polyhedron with given number of faces, edges and vertices are given. Is there a formula that gives me the number of polyhedron diagonals, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyhedronDiagonal.html ?

Comment: With $v$ vertices, $\frac{1}{2}v(v-1)$ counts the number of segments joining any two of them; these segments are either diagonals or edges. With $e$ edges, then, $\frac{1}{2}v(v-1) - e$ counts just the diagonals.

Comment: That page you link to contains a pretty strong hint.  Can you express the number of diagonals needed between every pair of vertices with your given information?

Comment: Do you count face diagonals _and_ space diagonals here? (Where "face diagonals" refers to diagonals that lie on a face and "space diagonals" refers to the others.)

Comment: I do not count face diagonals.

Comment: @hardmath I was thinking if it requires to count how many faces of different shapes there are.

Comment: If you want to exclude the "face diagonals" then yes, you would need the information about the polygons that appear as faces.  However you did not include such information in your problem setup (only a "given number of faces, edges, and vertices").  Note that Euler's famous formula $V+F-E=2$ makes any one of those "givens" redundant.

Answer (score 4):

In my comment, I failed to recognize that you were interested in just the "space diagonals". As you suspect, eliminating face diagonals requires knowing the shapes of the various faces.

---

Suppose, for $k = 3, 4, \dots$, there are $f_k$ faces with $k$ sides. Arguing as in my comment, we observe that the vertices of each such face determine $\frac12 k(k-1)$ segments, of which $k$ are edges; there are $\frac{1}{2} k(k-1)-k = \frac12 k(k-3)$ face diagonals per $k$-face.

Therefore, for a polyhedron with $v$ vertices, $e$ edges, and $f = f_3 + f_4 + \cdots$ faces, the number of space diagonals is given by
$$d = \frac12 v(v-1) - e - \frac12 \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}f_k\,k\,(k-3)$$

We can massage this expression a bit, using Euler's formula $v-e+f=2$ and writing $f$ in terms of the $f_k$s.

$$\begin{align}
d &= \frac12 v(v-1) - (v+f-2) - \frac12 \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} f_k k(k-3) \\[4pt]
&= 2 + \frac12 v(v-1) - v - \sum_{k=3}^\infty f_k - \frac12 \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} f_k k(k-3) \\[4pt]
&= 2 + \frac12 v(v-3) - \frac12 \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} f_k (k-1)(k-2)
\end{align}$$
This gives

> $$d = \frac12\left(\;4 + v(v-3) - \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} f_k (k-1)(k-2)\;\right)$$

---

As a sanity check, here are some test cases:

**Tetrahedron:** $v = 4$; $f = f_3 = 4$; $f_{\neq 3} = 0$
$$d = \frac12\left(\; 4 + 4(4-3) - 4 (3-1)(3-2) \;\right) = 0\;\checkmark$$
**Cube:** $v = 8$; $f = f_4 = 6$; $f_{\neq 4} = 0$
$$d = \frac12\left(\; 4 + 8(8-3) - 6 (4-1)(4-2) \;\right) = 4\;\checkmark$$
**Octahedron:** $v = 6$, $f = f_3 = 8$, $f_{\neq 3} = 0$
$$d = \frac12\left(\; 4 + 6(6-3) - 8 (3-1)(3-2) \;\right) = 3\;\checkmark$$
**[Truncated Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) (Soccer Ball):** $v = 60$, $f_5  =12$, $f_6 = 20$, $f_{\text{other}} = 0$
$$d = \frac12\left(\; 4 + 60(60-3) - 12(5-1)(5-2) - 20( 6-1)(6-2) \;\right) = 1440 \;\checkmark ?$$